# Private fork of a private repository

Tags: git, gitlab

I am fairly new to Git, and could not find the answer to my following question, so asking here instead. Please excuse me if it has already been answered.

I have a private Git repository on GitLab with I (owner) and 2 other members (maintainers). Now, they took a fork of that repository and made their forks private as well so I can't access their forks. Then, I have removed them from the project so only I am in the repository I created. So my question is that now that they have a fork, can they still pull updates (or even view commits) from my original repository or not?

Comment: @WaLinke I updated the reference . Thank you for your concern . If you want some tips on difference between GitHub and GitLab feel free to ask. Thanks Amer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can they still pull updates (or even view commits) from my original
>   repository

No they cannot.

> or even view commits

Yes they can if the repo is not `private` . If it is then they cannot do that either.

Reference is my own knowledge and GitLab forum and docs: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/15083